# kubuntu 18.04 eduroam(no CA) wifi problem on XPS13

Tags: networking, 18.04, kubuntu, network-manager, atheros

Recently updated to 18.04 and swiched to a different eduroam network which doesnt require a CA certificate on setup.
Since then I dont get a working internet connection.

It shows that it connects to the internet and it gets an IP adress but goes no further.

I have tried:

- rftkill unblock (all fine)
- nmcli off/on
- modprobe reload module
- deactivate/activate wifi in BIOS
- activate wifi channel 12/13

I talked to my university's helpdesk, sadly they couldnt help...

Any pointers appreciated!

edit: `sudo lshw -class network` output coming soon

edit2:

  `*-network

       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:e0:a5:1d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.47 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:135 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff`

Comment: I have the same problem and for me deactivating kwallet does the trick (see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kwallet-kf5/+bug/1770432))

Comment: Thank you for the comment, disabling kwallet didnt change anything for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I also realised that the eduroam I wanted to connect to had introduced the requirement for a certificate in the meantime. With that installed kwallet can stay enabled (no idea why it worked without CA though). But that doesn't seem to apply to your situation...